# How to extend default ALB controller policy using AWS CDK?

Tags: typescript, kubernetes, aws-cdk

I'm currently working on installing Goldilocks Helm chart to an EKS cluster. I have enabled an ingress for the tool's dashboard by manipulating a single Helm chart value. The problem is that, the ingress fails to deploy because default IAM policy for ALB controller is missing a single IAM policy statement. Therefore, I have created the required statement and linked it to the new policy.

When attempting to pass this custom IAM policy to the albController, I encountered the following `error: TypeError: policy.Statement` is not iterable. I'm facing difficulty in determining the expected property type for albController policy since it has no type defined (`any` type).

```
const elbAllowAddTags = new iam.PolicyStatement({
      resources: ["*"],
      effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
      actions: ["elasticloadbalancing:AddTags"],
      conditions: { "StringEquals": { "elasticloadbalancing:CreateAction": "CreateTargetGroup" } }
    })

    const elbPolicy = new iam.Policy(scope, "elbPolicy", {
      policyName: "elbPolicy",
      statements: [elbAllowAddTags],
    });
  
  const eksCluster = new eks.Cluster(scope, id, {
    albController: {
      ...
      policy: elbPolicy,
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not extend the default ALB controller policy but I solved the problem by upgrading ALBC version (see - https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/26442).

Answer (score 1):

Here an example from the [CDK Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_eks-readme.html)

```
declare const cluster: eks.Cluster;

const consoleReadOnlyRole = new iam.Role(this, 'ConsoleReadOnlyRole', {
assumedBy: new iam.ArnPrincipal('arn_for_trusted_principal'),
});
consoleReadOnlyRole.addToPolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
 actions: [
 'eks:AccessKubernetesApi',
 'eks:Describe*',
 'eks:List*',
 ],
 resources: [ cluster.clusterArn ],
 }));

// Add this role to system:masters RBAC group
cluster.awsAuth.addMastersRole(consoleReadOnlyRole)
```